# Ofuscando código Java com ProGuard

Tags: java, jar, ofuscação, proguard

## Problema:

Estou recebendo *warnings* do ProGuard e com isso não consigo ofuscar meu `.jar`, é a primeira vez que recebo estes avisos e com isso não consigo finalizar a ofuscação.

---

## Imagem com detalhes do problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Observação:**

Aplicação está funcionando, dentro do `.jar` estão todas as `API's` (dependências) necessárias, porém o ProGuard me dá esses *warnings*.

Comment: Tem certeza que a ofuscação não é finalizada? Warnings não deveriam interromper a ofuscação.

Comment: Tenho sim, Embora seja um "Warnings" recebe a seguinte mensagem "Please correct the above warnings first". Ela está na imagem.

Comment: "21 referências não resolvidas para classes e interfaces. Talvez você deva adicionar bibliotecas ou atualizar suas versões. Se seu código funciona sem as classes faltantes, você pode suprimir os alertas com a opção '-dontwarm'"

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre pois o apontamento padrão do Proguard faz menção somente para a lib `rt.jar`, faça o apontamento manual para a lib `jce.jar` que tudo estará resolvido.

Comment: vou testar, brother.

Comment: Devo apontar para o `rt.jar` e `jce.jar`? Seria de mais perguntar o que é `rt.jar` e `jce.jar`? O `rt` tenho uma noção, mas se poder ajudar. agradeço.

Comment: Tive que usar os dois, se usar `jce.jar` é `Warnning ` quase infinito. haha @Petter

Answer (score 0):

O erro tá te dando a solução:

> "21 referências não resolvidas para classes e interfaces. Talvez você
>   deva adicionar bibliotecas ou atualizar suas versões. Se seu código
>   funciona sem as classes faltantes, você pode suprimir os alertas com a
>   opção '**-dontwarm**'"

Comment: Acho que isto cabe mais como comentário, não achas?

Comment: Interessante, mas onde posso passar esse parâmetro, estou utilizando a interfase gráfica do proGuard em minhas buscas não encontrei um lugar passar ele.